# SourceTree is unresponsive

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

After changing permissions of (a lot of) files on git, SourceTree detected these unstaged changes and became unresponsive when trying to refresh. I quit it when the unresponsiveness was taking too long. After restarting the program again, it did not launch.

I checked the activity monitor and SourceTree is labeled 'application not responding'. Used Force quit and restarted the Mac. SourceTree is still not responding. How to run SourceTree again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I solved this one by deleting the folder `Library/Application Support/SourceTree`. After that I can now open the program again and scan my directory of projects for import.

The unresponsiveness was due to the changed file permissions of my project repo. Before I can open this said repo I accessed the project files' `.git/config` and set the `config.fileMode` to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to your account again

```
Sourcetree -> Prefereneces -> Accounts -> Click your account -> Connect account
```

This works for me